# How to not print ": " at the end?

Tags: c++

> Read in an input value for variable numInput. Then, read numInput integers from input and output each on the same line with the character ": " between each value.
>
> Ex: If the input is 5 10 -15 -95 -25 25, the output is: 10: -15: -95: -25: 25
>
> Note: ": " should not be at the beginning or end of the output.

Currently, the code prints `": "` at the end of the output. How to not print ": " at the end so as to get the expected output?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int numInput;

  cin >> numInput;
  while(cin >> numInput) {
    cout << numInput << ": ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the question isn't posted properly. Probably the question should be "how to not print `: `  at the end".

Comment: @kiner_shah , yes, you are correct.

Comment: how not to print : and the end, dont write the : after you output the number, write it before you output the next number, but not the first time, so you need a `bool first` to tell yourself its the first number

Comment: @pm100, could you elaborate more please?

Comment: @pm100 I wouldn't use a `bool`, I would just perform the 1st read outside of the loop, eg: `if (cin >> numInput) { cout << numInput; while (cin >> numInput) { cout << ": " << numInput; } }`

Comment: @kiner_shah this will print ": " before the first number. I need ": " not to be at the beginning or the end.

Comment: @HamdyMubarak, yeah my bad. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you very much. Now it's working.

Comment: It seems the first input is the number of integers? If yes, you should know which one is the last. Also Remy's solution is elegant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the solution proposed by @RemyLebeau in comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int numInput;
    std::string beginning = "";

    std::cin >> numInput;
  
    while (std::cin >> numInput) {
        std::cout << beginning << numInput;
        beginning = ": ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

`""` will be printed *before* the first input `int`. Subsequently `beginning` is changed to `": "` and that will be printed before each input. The end result is that `:`  will appear *after* every input except the last one.

Comment: This discards the first value of `numInput`?

Comment: I noticed that as well about the OP's code. The question, though, did not pertain to that behavior.

Comment: After re-reading the instructions, the 1st number should not be output. It is the count of following numbers. So the solution should not loop more than that many times.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `;` *after* each input number. You should instead output the 1st number by itself, and then output `;`  *before* each subsequent number, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numInput, input;
    if (cin >> numInput && numInput > 0) {
        if (cin >> input) {
            cout << input;
            while (--numInput > 0 && cin >> input) {
                cout << ": " << input;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/cPdDuY)